# Use same Selenium driver in another file/class

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to work with only one Chrome driver with different classes found in different files but it keeps opening a new window every time. I can't figure out how to use the same window.

**web_driver.py**

```
class WebPage:
    def __init__(self):
        self.options = Options()
        # self.options.add_argument('--headless')
        self.options.add_argument("--window-size=1280,720")
        self.options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
        self.options.add_argument('log-level=3')
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=self.options)

        self.url = 'https://website.net/'
        self.driver.get(self.url)

    def get_driver(self):
        return self.driver
```

**action.py**

```
from web_driver import WebPage


class Action:
    def __init__(self):
        self.wincap = WebPage().get_driver()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass an instance of WebPage into the class you want to use it.

So for you example class

```
class cl1:
    def __init__(self, web_page):
        self.wincap = web_page

class cl2:
    def __init__(self, web_page):
        self.wincap = web_page
web_page= WebPage()
obj1 = cl1(web_page)
```

Comment: Thank you! Writing this now, as I guess I needed more experience with OOP to understand your answer.